# Change default itunes store

Tags: itunes, itunes-store

I installed iTunes in Italy, (and I am outta there long ago) now it just connects to the italian itunes store. Is there any way short of renistalling, that I can convert it back to the english itunes store

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly, all you have to do is scroll down the page to the very bottom, and choose your country. There is no need to re-install.

Comment: grazie mille

there was an italian flag down there, I clicked that and it asked for my country